# Why doesn't MySQL return my Arabic columns with the correct charset in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, arabic

Hi guys. I have built a project in PHP where I enter data in Arabic. That works perfectly but when i do an query in PHP it appears in the web browser as "?????", question mark. I added this code but it doesn't work.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=utf8');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that the table/column where you are storing your data is also set to UTF-8 Collation.

Comment: yes i do that the tables and column all of them are utf8_general_ci

Comment: You have to get back to us with your results if you want the help to keep coming. If you solved the problem please provide your own question with an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: i solved it by put this                                           $con->set_charset('utf8'); .....thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

When you `SET NAMES utf8` this will convert the characters to `utf8` however if the default collation of the table is not `utf8` maybe `latin1` you will get data corruption. If you are set on using `utf8` as your character encoding then you will have to mysqldump your table and change the encoding in the corresponding dump file and then re import your data. make sure you use a text editor that does not use character encoding itself when editing the dump file.

Comment: the collation of the table and column all of them are utf8_general_ci .the database are entered in Arabic but the problem when i extract them .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the HTML page you are rendering has the correct charset as well. If you do a code inspection to see what the PHP service returned does it contain the correct characters? If so it's probably a matter of setting the HTML charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

To try, paste some unicode characters directly into your HTML, such as ✓ or ✔, and make sure they display correctly.

If they do you know the HTML is transferred correctly and interpreted correctly by the browser. If not you have to start there and fix your HTML charset.

Do you have a `DOCTYPE` set in your HTML? If not the browser might not care about your charset. Try setting `<!DOCTYPE html>` as the first line of your HTML.

Also make sure you set the header in PHP before you return ANYTHING else in the output of it will not have any effect.

Comment: @user3574242 Do you get them correctly from the backend? See my edit above.